# How can I get item from 3d numpy array via a 2d indices array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np


arr = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
indices = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 0]]) 

arr
# array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
#        [ 3,  4,  5],
#        [ 6,  7,  8]],
#
#       [[ 9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14],
#        [15, 16, 17]],
#
#       [[18, 19, 20],
#        [21, 22, 23],
#        [24, 25, 26]]]) 

indices
# array([[0, 2],
#       [1, 2],
#       [2, 0]])
```

I'd like to get items from `arr` by index of `indices`, just like:

```py
array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20]])
```

how can I get that?

Comment: `arr[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1]]`?

Comment: THANK YOU! That's it!~